# Is there a way to prevent redirection after form submission and still send the form data to the server?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to build a web app which uses Spotify API. I wanna use the input data that a user enters to call Spotify API on the server and send the result back to the front end. The problem is the page is redirected to 'http://localhost:4000/search_result' when I click the submit button. How do I prevent this?

main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingerCard from "./SingerCard";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      singers: [],
      tracks: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/");
    const singers = await res.json();
    this.setState({ singers });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="genres">
          <h2 className="header text-capitalize">
            top 10 tracks of famous singers
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.singers.map((elem) => (
            <SingerCard
              image={elem.images}
              name={elem.name}
              tracks={this.state.tracks}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
        <form
          action="http://localhost:4000/search_result"
          method="POST"
        >
          <label htmlFor="search">Search an artist: </label>
          <span>
            <input type="search" id="search" name="search" />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/search_result", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("The artist you are searching for" + req.body.search + ".");
  res.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`It's running on port ${port}`));
```

I tried to solve the issue by setting the server port to 3000 but I can't run the client side then.

Comment: where is the submit buton function code ?

Comment: Create Controlled Components (on every change inside form update their value in state) and on form submit, use `preventDefault()` and use the state object which has all values associated with form inputs

Comment: It's in the main.js file. Inside the render function.

Comment: Doesn't preventDefault prevent submission of the form? I wouldn't be able to use the form data on the server then.

Comment: Instead of having the `action` attribute in the form have a controlled form (react controls the value of the object).  [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) Inside your submit function you should have the `preventDefault()` so it will not refresh the page and the request - here you can use the fetch API, libraries such as axios and superagent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}` on your `<form>` tag, and then create `handleClick` function and request to your server with [axios](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) or [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) npm module:

```
<form onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();}}>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
</form>
```

i complete your main.js, test this code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingerCard from "./SingerCard";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      singers: [],
      tracks: [],
    };
    this.formPreventDefault = this.formPreventDefault.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/");
    const singers = await res.json();
    this.setState({ singers });
  }

  // handler recieves the `e` event object
  formPreventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/search_result')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="genres">
          <h2 className="header text-capitalize">
            top 10 tracks of famous singers
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.singers.map((elem) => (
            <SingerCard
              image={elem.images}
              name={elem.name}
              tracks={this.state.tracks}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
        <form
          onSubmit={this.formPreventDefault}
        >
          <label htmlFor="search">Search an artist: </label>
          <span>
            <input type="search" id="search" name="search" />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```